# How to launch the Internet Explorer 11 via Windows Start Search on Windows 10 (1709)?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, windows-10-v1709

Due of compatibility testing I often use the Internet Explorer 11. After I updated to Windows 10 1709 I can't launch it anymore via Windows Start Search, even though it's in the apps list nested in the folder `Windows Accessories`.

[image: Internet Explorer in Windows Accessories]

When I search `Internet Explorer` only Edge appears:

[image: Search for Internet Explorer]

Other apps from the `Windows Accessories` folder can be found:

[image: Other apps]

I've already reindexed all the links, without any success. Why is it like that?

Comment: For me, it shows up as soon as I type i.

Comment: for me [it also shows up as expected](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtziW2MYxY8Sk5l2r1aMEFD0HAP7uA)

Answer (score -3):

you could reinstall it https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17621/internet-explorer-downloads
sorry i dont know where it would be

hope this helps

Comment: IE11 cannot be “reinstalled” on Windows 8+

Comment: oh i did not know that i will test that by the way what would work?

Comment: In order for me to answer that question you would have to ask your own question.